# logarithms with exponents

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, exponentiation

I am supposed to solve for $x$ when
$\log_{10}\big((x+1)^2\big) = 2.$
I used the log power rule and then got
$2\cdot \log_{10}(x+1) = 2.$
When I graph both these functions, I get two different graphs. Why does the power rule not work here? And how should I attack this problem?

Comment: Probably better to get rid of the logarithm first as you then get an easily solved quadratic. Note $(x+1)^2\ge 0$ though equality raises an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is a non-zero real number, then $\log_{10}(a^2)=2\log_{10}\left(\color{red}{|a|}\right)$. (The "rule" $\log_{10}(a^2)=2\log_{10}(a)$ is actually only valid when $a$ is positive.) Applying this to the problem at hand, we get
$$
\log_{10}\left((x+1)^2\right)=2\log_{10}\left(|x+1|\right)=2\implies \log_{10}\left(|x+1|\right)=1 \, .
$$
By the definition of logarithms, this means that $|x+1|=10^1$. If $x+1\ge0$, then this equation becomes $x+1=10$ and so $x=9$. If $x+1<0$, then the equation becomes $-(x+1)=10$ and so $x=-11$.

Comment: How is it possible to change the inner parenthesis to an absolute value. Won't that change the equation? I graphed the one with parenthesis and the one with an absolute value and it was the same. How does that work?

Comment: The logarithm of x is only defined for x greater than 0.

Comment: @AmruthArunkumar: I don't really understand your question, sorry. Could you elaborate please? Anyway, it is definitely true that $\log_{10}(a^2)=2\log_{10}(|a|)$. You can see a graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). To prove it, we should first prove that $\log_{10}(x^2)=2\log_{10}(x)$ for positive $x$. Then, since $a^2=|a|^2$, we can write
$$
\log_{10}(a^2)=\log_{10}(|a|^2)\, .
$$
Let $x=|a|$. Since $x$ is positive,
$$
\log_{10}(x^2)=2\log_{10}(x) \, .
$$
Then, substitute $|a|$ back in for $x$ to get $2\log_{10}(|a|)$, as desired.

Comment: I think I understand now actually. Thanks very much!

Comment: @AmruthArunkumar: No problem! I'm glad I could help. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: @AmruthArunkumar: Sorry, the first graph wasn't saved. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ya94tu5ohd) are plots of $y=\log_{10}(x^2)$ and $y=2\log_{10}(|x|)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can bring to common base:
$$\log_{10} \left((x+1)^2\right)=2 \iff \log_{10}\left((x+1)^2\right)=\log_{10}10^2 \iff \\
(x+1)^2=100 \iff x+1=\pm 10 \iff x_1=-11, x_2=9.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that$$\log_{10}\bigl((x+1)^2\bigr)=\log_{10}\bigl(|x+1|^2\bigr)=2\log_{10}|x+1|.$$And $\log_{10}|x+1|$ is defined for every number other than $-1$, just as $\log_{10}\bigl((x+1)^2\bigr)$, and unlike $\log_{10}(x+1)$.